# TypeError: Cannot set property closed of #<Readable> which has only a getter at FsReadStream.close

Tags: javascript, angular, audio

**When I click the button to play the error the app throws the error and shuts down**

`playSound(): void{let audio = new Audio(); audio.src = './assets/notification/notification.wav'; audio.load(); audio.play(); }`

`<button (click)=" playSound()"> <mat-icon>trash</mat-icon></button>`

## I haven't found much documentation on this yet.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use something like

```js
myAudioElement.addEventListener("canplaythrough", (event) => {
  /* the audio is now playable; play it if permissions allow */
  myAudioElement.play();
});
```

There is documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play